# PHP5: Iterating through a list of child nodes (equivalent of child_nodes())?

Tags: php, xml

All,

I have an XML document that looks something like this:

```
<root>
    <profile>
        <childA>
        <childB>
        <childC>
    <profile>
    <blah>
    <blah>
    <foo>
    <bar>
<root>
```

I'd like to be able to grab the 'profile' node, then iterate through it's children ('childA', 'childB', etc)

So far, my code looks like this:

```
$doc = new DomDocument();
$doc->loadXML(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$profile_node = $doc->getElementsByTagName("profile")->item(0);
```

So far, so good. $profile_node has what I want.

In PHP4, I guess you'd do something like this:

```
$childnodes = $profile_node->child_nodes();
foreach ($childnodes as $node) {
    // do something with this node
}
```

But, I can't find the equivalent of child_nodes() in PHP5.

Since I'm pretty much a noob regarding PHP, I'd really appreciate a code example, so I can see the exact syntax.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [php manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php), the DomNode class has a public $childNodes variable. You can access it directly:

```
foreach ($profile_node->childNodes as $node) {
    // do something with this node
}
```

Comment: Zed - Thanks for your response!

My apologies - I should have mentioned that I don't know PHP well at all. So, I don't know the syntax for creating a loop that will iterate through the child nodes.

Can you provide a code example (e.g., using a foreach loop)?

No worries if not.

Comment: You can just replace your foreach loop with the given foreach loop and delete the line directly above it.

Comment: Correct. This completely replaces your code below "In PHP4, I guess you'd do something like this"

Comment: Just a note - I screwed up my own code above. Instead of "$profile_node = $doc->getElementsByTagName("profile");", it should read: "$profile_node = $doc->getElementsByTagName("profile")->item(0);"

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to read, I would suggest using the [simplexml](https://www.php.net/simplexml) package:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('php://input');
$childnodes = $xml->xpath("//profile/child::*");
foreach($childnodes as $node){
  // do something
}
```

The SimpleXML package and the DOM package are interchangeable: you can import the SimpleXML into DOM objects using [`dom_import_simplexml()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dom-import-simplexml.php).